# How to I adapt this RegEx to allow dashes?

Tags: regex, url-rewriting

I currently have this:

`^(\w+)[/]*$` as my RegEx for URL rewriting in IIS.

Which won't allow...

```
/1st-source-capital-corporation
```

How can I adapt it to allow URLS which contain Alphanumeric, underscores and dashes?

Comment: add a dash in the character class that has `/` in it already

Comment: This regex only allows one alphanumeric word, followed by any number of slashes. That's not really the regex you're using, is it? It matches `foo/////` but it doesn't match `foo/bar`...

Answer (score 0):

Don't you really want something like this, assuming your example input data is correct?

```
^(\w+)/(.*)$
```

Note the example is *NOT* a URL.

With the revised example, I have a revised regex:

```
^/(.*)$
```

Comment: @ChrisDowdeswell It works on your example, in the sense that $1 contains .com and $2 contains 1st-source-capital-corporation.  Describe what you want better and people can answer better.

Comment: Really sorry I should clarify the .com was there to insinuate it was URL the Regex need only work for the following paths after...

Comment: @ChrisDowdeswell: You have not explained why my example regex doesn't work.  What are you trying to match that this does not?  What are you trying to not match that this does?

Comment: `.*` matches *everything* (except newline, which has no business in a URL) so your problem is almost certainly somewhere else.

Comment: Sorry I see the problem now, my URLs don't end with a slash therefore the RegEx was failing.

Is it possible to update to reflect a situation where a final / might be missed? Thanks

Comment: @ChrisDowdeswell: Most like just say nothing (without putting the trailing $) which will allow everything, but if you wanted to explicitly say something to match everything, then ".*$"

Answer (score 0):

This is POSIX:

```
^([[:alnum:]]\|[_-/])*$
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, to include the "-", because it is a range delimiter for character classes, you need to include it first between square brackets, so you'd need something like "^([-_[:alnum:]/]+)$".